# Does Firefox 8 Support mp4?

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

Does Firefox 8 (win/64) Support mp4?

I cannot find any mention on MDN of support for mp4 AND it's not playing mp4 files locally on server.

Please advise.

sleeper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox does not support the mp3/mp4 technologies, as aspects of them are licensed.

See the 'official' support list for Firefox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

More about why Firefox avoids it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Here's another link:  http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/765888.  Of course you can PLAY them on Firefox - the user just needs to install the appropriate (licensed, encumbered) codecs and player (either a plugin, or a standalone .exe that can be invoked from the browser).

Comment: Cool. Now I know I'm not crazy. Thanks!

Comment: @Vigrond weird... tried to give you credit for the answer but got a pop "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes". Whats that all about?

Comment: @sleeper I think you have to wait 15 minutes before you can 'accept' an answer